# logback don't throws any exception when hard disk is full

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

We using `slf4j` + `logback` for logging in my application.
Application logs are very important for our application.
In production environment logs is very amount.
Sometime hard disk will full and `logback` don`t throws any exception to our application and application worked fine and continue.
I enabled`debug`attribute of logback configuration and see exception is`disk full`.
I search at web for soloution and don`t find any ways.
I found a ways myself, write a thread for checking hard disk size.
My questin is: is there better ways for this target?
(I see a similer question in stakoverflow but not has newer answer.)

Comment: Why don't you make a wrapping appender that does what you want when it encounters an `IOException`?

Comment: If disk is full, raising some exception will not help to save something. So advice to monitor disk in separate thread was actually good because you will be able to do some action (send angry mail, stop application) before disk will be full.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7683755/843804

Comment: My goal of this question is understand is there any solution already or I must do myself solution.